# Randomly select and assign values to given number of rows in python dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, random

How can I randomly select and assign values to given number of rows in python dataframe.
Col B contains only 1's and 0's.
Suppose I have a dataframe as below

```
Col A    Col B
  A        0
  B        0
  A        0
  B        0
  C        0
  A        0
  B        0
  C        0
  D        0
  A        0
```

I aim to randomly chose 5% of the rows and change the value of Col B to 1. I saw df.sample() but that wont allow me to do inplace changes to the column data

Comment: `np.random.choice([0,1], len(df['Col B']), p= [0.95, 0.05])`?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Random library. Random has it's own sample function.

```
import Random
randindx = Random.sample(arr.between(0, dataframe['Col B'].size), dataframe['Col B'].size//20)
```

Considering 5%, you need to divide by 20.

Answer (score 0):

You can first use the `sample` method to get the random `5%` of examples and get hold of their indices like so:

`samples_indices = df.sample(frac=0.05, replace=False).index`

With the knowledge of the indices, `loc` method can be used to update the values corresponding to the examples.

`df.loc[samples_indices, 'Col B'] = 1`